# battery show percentage (and time if possible)

Tags: unity, indicator, battery

My battery has some broken cells making the battery drop from 60% straight down to 30% in a few seconds.
This makes the estimated time remaining extremely unreliable for a full charge but the percentages are quite reliable. For low percentages the time is useful once again.

So my search for a fix to show the percentage as well as the time yielded an [gnome extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/230/battery-remaining-time/) that does exactly that but since I'm using unity that wouldn't work.
Does anyone know an similar extension for unity??

Answer (score 0):

Right Click...
[image]

This is Ubuntu 13.10, with `unity 7.1.2`, with [`unity-tweak-tool`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-tweak-tool/) installed.

Comment: Aah, there's the problem.
I've still got version 7.0.0. time to do a release upgrade (totally forgot about the eol of 13.04)

Comment: 4 days ago - I forgot as well :D - best get on with it before they archive the repositories.